# Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges? MySQL Workbench ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, workbench, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed MySQL Workbench 8.0 on my ubuntu 20.04 machine. But it Says

`your connection attempt failed for user 'root' to the mysql server at localhost:3306`

[image]

I tried using user Password, 'YES', and without using Password. but this error is a popup.

Comment: Your user/password combination is wrong, or root is disabled or don't have permissions from localhost.

Comment: @Alejandro How I get the correct Password. I tried many times.

Comment: If you installed the server yourself, you've created it during the initial configuration. Maybe you left it blank or put something. In the most extreme case, uninstall the whole server and reinstall it, taking note of the password you put.